# c# uwp app using child views is working fine on Desktop, but it Doesn't show child views running on ARM-Remote Machine (Raspbery pi3b+)

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, iot, windows-10-iot-core

i have a c# app using uwp, this application use child views/pages using code like:

```
static private async Task _LoadNewPagex(System.Type frm)
{
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplicationView newView = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;
    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame frame = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame();
        frame.Navigate(frm);
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Activate();
        newViewId = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    bool viewShown = await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync (newViewId, Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay );
}
```

in the Mainpage.xaml i have a button and the call to the the creation of the new child view/page

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _LoadNewPagex(App.Current, typeof(emptyx))
}
```

When i'm debugging the code all is working fine, and the child views are working fine, my trouble is when i test the application into the device (raspberry pi 3b+) using the ARM-Remote Machine Option, it deploys and loads the application into the pi-windows 10 iot and show the main page, but when i press the button the child view/page is never showed up.

is there any special configuration, or any special procedure to make this works ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows IoT Core does not support multiple view. In Headed mode, the IoT Shell will launch a single registered startup app that will show its UI in **full screen** (also known as a Headed app). You can use following code to navigate to a new page:

```
public static void LoadNewPagex(System.Type frm)
{
    var rootFrame = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    rootFrame.Navigate(frm);
}
```